# Ruby on rails: Google API dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Hey guys I have an error when getting some tokens from google. Do you have any ideas about this error? And let me know how I can solve this error.

> [{"domain"=>"usageLimits", "reason"=>"dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp"=>"https://code.google.com/apis/console"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."}}

My fetching code:

```
    def self.request_tokens(code)
      Request.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', {
        client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: code,
      })
    end

    def self.request_profile(access_token)
      Request.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=#{access_token}")[:body]
    end
```

Add:

I have already added API key like this.

```
      def self.request_profile(access_token)

    　　# Add api key but failed
        Request.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=#{access_token}?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX")[:body]

    　　# try like this but failed
        plus = Google::Apis::PlusV1::PlusService.new
        plus.key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        plus.authorization = access_token

      end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. You're overusing Google's API, so they're not letting you use it for the rest of the day unless you sign up for an API key. https://code.google.com/apis/console, the link in your error, will let you do that.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, How can I signup Google's API?

Comment: FYI This error message is not the quota exceeded error message.   This is the not adding any authentication to the request message.

Answer (score 0):

> "Daily Limit for **Unauthenticated** Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",

Means that you are trying to access a Google api without being authenticated or using an api key (using a valid client). In order to access all google apis you must have created a project on Google developer console.  If you are accessing public data you can use an api key if you are accessing private user data you will need to use Oauth2.

You appear to have tried to set the client id in your code.  The issue is that its not being applied properly to your request.  I am not a ruby dev so can not assist you in debugging your code how ever google has a number of ruby tutorials [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/aaa_oauth)

as well as [use api key](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/api-keys)

```
require 'google/apis/plus_v1'

plus = Google::Apis::PlusV1::PlusService.new
plus.key = 'api_key'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for kind reply, I'll try to do that.